# How to send image in a JSON API request to an Express server

Tags: node.js, json, api, express

> As of writing this, I haven't found an answer that answers my question.

I am building a REST API for an ExpressJS backend server, that has multiple endpoints. One of them is called `/company/create`, which accepts `company_name` and `company_logo`. I'm storing all data in a MySQL database with the help of Sequelize.

I've set the data type of `company_logo` to `Sequelize.BLOB`. I'm willing to change the data type if there's a better approach.

My question is, when doing a POST request to `/company/create`, how do I send the image? The data in the POST request looks something like this:

```json
{
   "company_name": "Example Company",
   "company_logo": ?
}
```

I want to test the API before I start using it in the frontend, and I don't how to pass the image into this request.

I hope my question is clear, and not difficult to understand. If it helps, this API is going to be use for a Flutter app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I understood is you want to test your API before integrating it with the front end. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
To test your API endpoint that accepts an image file, you can use tools like Postman or simple curl will also work.

The POST request sent by Postman or curl will send the file data as binary data, not as a BLOB data type. The server will need to convert the binary data to a BLOB data type and then store it in the database.
In the case of ExpressJS & Sequelize ORM, you can use the `req.file.buffer` property to get the binary data of the uploaded file,
and then save it to the database as a BLOB data type. You may want to try `multer` npm package for image upload process purposes.

```
const company_logo = req.file.buffer;
```

Follow these steps for the postman

- Open Postman and create a new request.
- Select the `POST` method type.
- Add the request URL to `http://localhost:3000/company/create`
- Select the `form-data` option for the body.
- Add a field `company_name` and its value`Example Company`
- Add a field `company_logo` and the value of the image
  file.
- Click the Send button.

Alternatively, you use curl as follows,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F "company_name=Example Company" \
-F "company_logo=@/path/to/image.jpg" \
http://localhost:3000/company/create
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I left this issue aside for a while. But this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!!